# Get Objective Value from Pyomo every X iterations?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, operations-research

Is there a way to get from `pyomo` a list of the objective values at every `X` iterations, especially when using `cbc`?

The usual way of running the solver only returns the final solver results.

```
results = SolverFactory('cbc').solve(model)
results.write()
print(model.obj()) # final objective value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `tee=True` option to your call to `solve` to print the solver log to the screen. Most solvers will print out the value of the objective function at every iteration.

```
SolverFactory('cbc').solve(model, tee=True)
```

Pyomo doesn't automatically load/record solver information at intermediate iterations but you could always write a simple parser to read the solver log file into Python and extract the values you want. An example of doing this for Ipopt can be found here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/contrib/parmest/utils/ipopt_solver_wrapper.py